# Chrome offline storage not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, storage, offline, html5-filesystem

I'm trying to develop a solution for persisting large data files needed by my web app without direct interactions with the user. IndexedDB has limitation up to 2GB if I'm correct, and I'm looking for something more like 10GB. I've managed to create a solution with FileSystem API and Chrome's Quota Management API which is working on Windows and Android devices. However it's not working on iOS. On iOS I'm not able to use FileSystem API because I get this error:

> DOMException: The operation failed because it would cause the application to exceed its storage quota.

Requesting bigger quota is done via Chrome's Quota Management API mentioned above, but on Chrome running on iOS navigator.webkitPersistentStorage is undefined. It's working just fine on Windows and Android. There is no iOS limitation mentioned in official docs, actually nowhere in the Internet as far as I searched. Has anyone overcame this issue or knows where it could be reported to reach Chrome support?

Resources worth mentioning:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/offline_storage/#requestQuota
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem

Comment: if you look at the version history  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history, it shows that ios has always had a different rendering engine. Could this affect things

Comment: This looks like a good explanation :) Still not much information about those differences can be found, both chrome docs and safari docs are pretty quiet about storage limitations and managing large data chunks unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Quota Management API is not available on iOS. However in iOS Safari you get asked to give more storage if you use indexedDB and it does not seem to be limited at 2 GB. You can test it with a website like this: https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I was able to go past 2GB limit using indexedDB. However, there are incremental requests for permissions emitted by the browser around every ~200MB which is pretty uncomfortable as I plan to load about 10GB of data on 1 user interaction (for offline mode basically). Also when user clicks "deny" once, which can be even by mistake - the whole process is stopped, there are no more consequent permissions requests on new files or even on new action with new files unless I completely reset cache OR refresh the page. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: It'd be great to be able to request larger chunk of disk space at once, and handle somehow situation in which client clicks "deny". One more thing is that I've found information about "eviction policy" on iOS and I can't find any way to request persistance as Quota Management API is disabled as you have mentioned and navigator.storage API is disabled as well.

Comment: Unfortunately all of this is a limitation of Apple's Webkit and every Browser on iOS needs to use it.

Comment: thanks for answer, so no suggestions on programmatically requesting more storage limit, eh? I see that there is no point in asking on official Apple forum as well since similar question is waiting to be answered for more then 4 years...
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/73456